# React Pre-Render Conditionals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Before I load my React App I need to check 2 conditions

1. User is Logged in, if not redirect to login page
2. All of the
   User Settings fetched using API, if not display a loading screen.

So, inside render method, I have below conditions:

```
if (!this.isUserLoggedIn()) return <NotifyPleaseLogin />;
else if (!this.state.PageCheck) {
  return (
    <PageLoading
      clientId={Config.clientId}
      setPageReady={this.setPageReady()}
    />
  );
} else {
  return "Display the page";
```

In this scenario, what I expect to see happen is that, if user is not logged in, user redirected to login page. If user logged in and currently page is fetching the API query, user will see the PageLoading component (loading screen) and lastly if page is ready, the page will get displayed.

Right now I am getting `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.` error, which is because I am doing a setState update within Render method of the parent and also I am getting `TypeError: props.setPageReady is not a function    at PageLoading.js:29` error when I try to run parent's function that sets the state of PageReady to true like below

```
setPageReady() {
    this.setState({ PageCheck: true });
  }
```

How can I set this up so child can display a loading page until the page is ready (During this child can do an API call and retrieve user settings) then let parent know all settings are retrieved and are in the redux so parent can proceed loading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by adding more states to actively control your component:

```
state = {
    isAuthorized: false,
    pagecheck: false    
};
```

We move the authorization check to a lifecylcle-method so it doesn't get called every render.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        this.setState({ 
            isAuthorized: true                
        });
    }   
}
```

Using our state, we decide what to render.

```
render() {
    const {
      pagecheck,
      isAuthorized
    } = this.state;

    if(!isAuthorized){
      return <NotifyPleaseLogin />;
    }

    if(!pagecheck) {
      return (
        <PageLoading
          clientId={Config.clientId}
          setPageReady={() => this.setPageReady()}
        />
      );    
    }

    return "Display the page";
}
```

**Note:** Previously you passed `this.setPageReady()` to Pageloading. This however executes the function and passes the result to Pageloading. If you want to pass the function you either need to remove the braces `this.setPageReady` or wrap it into another function `() => this.setPageReady()`

Comment: Thank you!! Clear and straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass PageCheck as prop from Parent to   and show/hide loader in  component based on that prop.

```
  <PageLoading
      clientId={Config.clientId}
      pageCheck={this.state.PageCheck}
     setPageReady={this.setPageReady}
    />
```

Then call setPageReady inside the success and error of the API call that you make in the child function:

```
axios.get(api)
.then((response) => {
     //assign or do required stuff for success
   this.props.setPageReady();
})
.catch((error) => {
    //do error related stuff
this.props.setPageReady();  //as you need to hide loader for error condition as well
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
state = {
    isAuthorized: false,
    pageCheck: false    
};
```

---

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        this.setState({ 
            isAuthorized: true                
        });
    }   
}
```

---

```
{!this.state.isAuthorized ?
  <NotifyPleaseLogin />
:
(!this.state.pageCheck ?
  <PageLoading
      clientId={Config.clientId}
      setPageReady={this.setPageReady()}
   />
  :
  "Display the page")  
}
```